# Spring MVC return object from JSP

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have a Spring MVC controller that sends a list to the view:

```
modelAndView.addObject("myList", List<foo>);
```

On the JSP, I iterate over this list creating a table where each row is a form with a submit button representing one foo instance.  How can I get the single instance of foo represented by the row into the next controller?  I tried putting it in an input type="hidden" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A JSP is processed and rendered into HTML, which is just text.

When you submit a form, the browser takes the values of the `<input>` fields and serializes them in a specific format. With the typical `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, the following `<input>` elements

```
<form action="/some/url" method="POST">
    <input name="someField" value"someValue" type="text" />
    <input name="someOtherField" value"someOtherValue" type="text" />
    <input name="submit" value"submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

The serialized format will look something like

```
someField=someValue&someOtherField=someOtherValue&submit=submit
```

Spring will take this `String` from the body of the request as request parameters and try to reconstruct your command object (ex. `foo`) from its values. The request above could be mapped to a class like

```
class Foo {
    private String someField;
    private String someOtherField;

    public String getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    public void setSomeField(String someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    public String getSomeOtherField() {
        return someOtherField;
    }

    public void setSomeOtherField(String someOtherField) {
        this.someOtherField = someOtherField;
    }
}
```

Any fields it can't map, it ignores.

Comment: So you're saying that each form needs to have hidden input's for all of the properties of the Foo class...and then in the controller, something like:

@RequestMapping(value={"/secondRequest"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView secondRequest(Foo foo, HttpServletRequest request)

Is that right?

Comment: @Greg They don't need to be hidden. Also, although what you have is equivalent, you should have `@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo` instead of just `Foo foo`.

Comment: Well I don't display all of the properties to the user, so some would need to be hidden...but this seems sort of overly complicated for what I want to do.  Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: @Greg Look into flash attributes.